# jinja2 - loop through a dictionary

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I am new with `Jinja2` maybe my question is noobie but I can't understand it.

So I use `Jinja2` for an `Ansible` task as a template to create a file, I have a dictionary defined in the Default Variable file like:

```
test123:
  testA:
    name: test1
    number: 1
    path: /tmp/test.txt
  testB:
    name: test2
    number: 2
    path: /tmp/test.txt
```

Now in my `Jinja2` file, I want to loop through this dictionary and print everything defined in the dictionary.

I tried various examples but nothing does the right thing.

For example:

```
{% for item in test123.values() -%}
{{ item.name }}="{{ item.number }}"
{%- endfor %} 
{% for item in test123.testB.values() -%}
    {{ item.name }}="{{ item.number }}"
{%- endfor %}
```

Error Message:

> fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg":
>   "AnsibleUndefinedVariable:
>   'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute
>   'name'"}

I thought maybe the best thing would be to create a while loop for this and print everything out but since in `Jinja2` there is no while loop I am a little bit confused how to do it.

Do someone has an idea how to achieve that? So once again the goal is to print everything from the dictionary in the `Jinja2` file.

Thank you in advance

Comment: That is not a Python dictionary..not sure about Ansible.

Comment: What python version on target host?

Comment: @amanb I used this manual for creating a dictionary in ansible: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/dict.html
( in the example at the top you can see the example) 
so jinja2 can't do anything with that dictionary?

Comment: @ozlevka python version on the target host is: 
Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below would create a output with all the user names in it

```
{% for item in test123.values() %}
name of the user: {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Output format:

```
name of the user: test1
name of the user: test2
```

If you need something in specific format let me know the desired output

Comment: Works as expected :) so the .values() calls all the values in the dict right?

Comment: yes. then you can access the subelements using the item.name and {{ }} is used for variable replacement in jinja2

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to use [dict2items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter) filter. The template below

```
{% for item in test123|dict2items %}                                                
{{ item }}                                                                          
{% endfor %}

{% for item in test123|dict2items %}
key: {{ item.key }}
value.number: {{ item.value.number }}
value.name: {{ item.value.name }}
value.path: {{ item.value.path }}

{% endfor %}
```

gives

```
{'value': {u'path': u'/tmp/test.txt', u'name': u'test1', u'number': 1}, 'key': u'testA'}
{'value': {u'path': u'/tmp/test.txt', u'name': u'test2', u'number': 2}, 'key': u'testB'}

key: testA
value.number: 1
value.name: test1
value.path: /tmp/test.txt

key: testB
value.number: 2
value.name: test2
value.path: /tmp/test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a python dictionary. however if you got a list of dicts:

```
test123 = [
    {'name':'test1', 'number': 1, 'path': '/tmp/test.txt'},
    {'name':'test2', 'number': 2, 'path': '/tmp/test.txt'},
    ]
```

this jinja code should work:

```
{% for item in test123 %}
    {{ item.name }}="{{ item.number }}"
{% endfor %}
```

of course, you need to pass this dict to your render function (you dont post your controller code). No idea if this apply well to ansible.